# Auto adjust the width based on the option selected by the user from the dropdown - Reacr

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I have a custom component called `<Dropdown>` to which i cant make much changes. This component looks something like this:

```
<DropDown
        id="QuestionBank"
        name="QuestionBank"
        options={props.questionOptions}
        changeHandler={props.questionChangeHandler}
        value={props.topicFilter.questionBank.is}
        inline
/>
```

The dropdown arrow adjusts itself to the largest text in the list which is coming from `props.questionOptions`But i want the dropdown arrow to be dynamic based on the length of the user selected text. Otherwise there seems to be a large gap between the text and the arrow when selected with smaller option.

I tried making some changes in the css for the width,max-width property but it doesnt seem to work fine.

I also tried to write a function which calculates the length of the user selected option but I wasnt sure how to adjust the width of the `<DropDown>` component as I cant seem to change much here.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to have flexible dropdown size you can use this css styles, but additional css i wrote Dopdown component because you didn't mentioned any code in this component so i confused(everyone may confuse!).

```css
/* Hide the default arrow */
.DropDown select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* Add padding for the pseudo-element */
  padding-right: 20px;
}

/* Create a pseudo-element for the custom arrow */
.DropDown select::after {
  content: '▼'; /* You can use any custom arrow character or an image */
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px; /* Adjust the position as needed */
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const DynamicWidthDropDown = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const dropDown = document.getElementById('QuestionBank');
    dropDown.addEventListener('change', adjustWidth);
    adjustWidth();
    return () => {
      dropDown.removeEventListener('change', adjustWidth);
    };
  }, []);

  const adjustWidth = () => {
    const dropDown = document.getElementById('QuestionBank');
    const selectedText = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].text;
    const width = selectedText.length * 10;
    dropDown.style.width = `${width}px`;
  };

  return (
    <DropDown
      id="QuestionBank"
      name="QuestionBank"
      options={props.questionOptions}
      changeHandler={props.questionChangeHandler}
      value={props.topicFilter.questionBank.is}
      inline
    />
  );
};
```